# Conjugate る-ending verbs into negative form

Tags: grammar, conjugations, negation

Sorry if this question has been asked before. I tried to look around for an answer but couldn't find it.

I just want to state before that my question is not regarding the verb ある or verbs with kanji + multiple hiragana (for example 負ける). The question is regarding verbs with kanji + single る.

I have some issues with the negative form of verbs ending with る. I know the basic rules for converting a verb into negative form (adding an あ-sound + ない) but i cant get a grasp on these. Sometimes it is らない and sometimes just ない. Is there a rule to when it is らない and when its just ない or is it just an irregularity?

Examples:

- 出る -> 出ない
- 降る -> 降らない
- 着る -> 着ない
- 切る -> 切らない

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are generally 3 categories of verbs, and their names depend on which textbook you use. There are Type 1 (五段), Type 2 (一段), and Irregular verbs.

- The conjugation for negative form for Type 1 verbs:

  - Change the final sound to the corresponding one that ends in -a, then append ない
  - 切る→切ら→切らない
  - 歩く→歩か→歩かない
  - 会う→会わ→会わない　（not　会あない）
  - 帰る→帰ら→帰らない
- The conjugation for negative form for Type 2 verbs:

  - drop る and append ない
  - 出る→出ない
  - 見る→見ない
  - 変える→変えない

All Type 2 (一段) verbs end in -iru or -eru. 
The **converse is not true**; i.e. verbs that end in -iru and -eru may also be Type 1 (五段).

- There are two other verbs ending in る – namely する and くる – that are irregular:

  - する→しない
  - くる→こない

Comment: Ok, so just to clarify; The only way to know **for sure** how to conjugate them is to know if the verb is 五段 or 一段? There are no reading/meaning patterns that tells this?

Comment: If the sound that comes first is in the い or え column, then yes, you just have to know what category the verb is in to be able to conjugate it. If it's something else, like, for instance, 降る (where the ふ comes from the う column), it can't be an 一段 verb.

Comment: @Sebastian Yeah pretty much.  変える and 帰る are both かえる and they conjugate differently. You can probably get some intuition if a word is 五段 or 一段 after spending some time around words, but yeah the only way to know **for sure** is to know which type it is.

Comment: @Sebastian [This page has complete conjugation schemes](http://pomax.github.io/nrGrammar/#section-7-Conjugation_Schemes) if you want to investigate further.